# Can we activate the regexp_like operator in PeopleSoft Query Manager (4-tier)

Tags: regex, oracle, peoplesoft

As I am just learning more and more about regular expressions in programming languages, and especially all the performance benefits we can take out of this for string manipulations, I see that of course Oracle supports regular expressions.

But on PeopleSoft (4-tier), within the "Query Manager", we can only select the "Like" operator and of course, each time we use it, the query performances drop down dramatically (logical)...

**Does anyone know if this is something which can be activated as a parameter or it does not exist at all as considered too complex for a "normal" end user?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a performance perspective a REGEXP_LIKE is no different to a LIKE.  It is even less likely to use an index.  All it might to is return a more focused result set.

PeopleSoft Query Manager (4-tier) is aimed at non-technical people. Many programmers have problems understanding regular expressions: I think people who can't write SQL are going to *really* struggle with regex.

Comment: All right, that's what I thought as the best explanation why I cannot find this operator in 4-tier Query Manager. As I am a former PeopleSoft designer, I am the only one now in my business team to really have technical programming skills which is why I asked the question we never know). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never, but for the record, I do use Regular Expressions in PeopleSoft Query (even in 2 tier mode).  You need to use the "EQUAL TO" operator and enter your regular expression as a PeopleSoft Query expression value.

For a specific report I had to let users enter up to 5 prompt parameters for Degree Checkout Status (DEGR_CHKOUT_STAT). The specific values and number of values changed based on school and user running the report.

I created a 30 character long prompt (referred to as :3 below) and called it DEGR_CHKOUT_STAT.   You can send "AW,PN,IR,EG,AG" or just "AW" for prompt :3 and the query works.

Expression 1: A.DEGR_CHKOUT_STAT 
Operator: equal to
Expression 2: ANY(REGEXP_SUBSTR( :3, '[^,]+',1,1 ) , REGEXP_SUBSTR( :3, '[^,]+',1,2 ) , REGEXP_SUBSTR( :3, '[^,]+',1,3 ) , REGEXP_SUBSTR( :3, '[^,]+',1,4 ) , REGEXP_SUBSTR( :3, '[^,]+',1,5 )  )

Since I am new I don't have enough reputation points to post a picture but I can email it to you upon request.

Comment: Hi Erol Irez, I just saw your answer! Thanks a lot for this answer, I'm sorry I also reply very late but I'll check that very soon. My PeopleSoft is still hanging here for some months so for my own curiosity, i'll check that ;)